# how can i install camera1394 package?

Tags: ros, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i wanted to run 2 usb cameras as stereo cameras and wanted to publish :
/my_stereo/left/camera_info
/my_stereo/left/image_raw
/my_stereo/right/camera_info
/my_stereo/right/image_raw
/my_stereo_both/parameter_descriptions
/my_stereo_both/parameter_updates
/my_stereo_l/parameter_descriptions
/my_stereo_l/parameter_updates
/my_stereo_r/parameter_descriptions
/my_stereo_r/parameter_updates

I am new to linux and ROS.plz help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222433/how-can-i-install-camera1394-package?/) by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2015-12-13**:
I don't think the Camera1394 package is the one you are after - it is used for Firewire connected cameras.  I expect that you would need two instances of a USB camera driver such as [libuvc_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-14**:
What camera models do you have? (A few USB cameras do support the IIDC standard and can work with camera1394.)

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-14**:
actually i have also tried to use uvc_camera but when i run roslaunch camera_node.launch it throws:
Setting auto_focus is not supported
Setting focus_absolute is not supported

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-14**:
joq i am using a basic usb cam from quantum "http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00L5AWKUM?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I doubt that camera supports the IIDC protocol, so it will not work with camera1394.

You'll need a ROS USB camera driver, instead. There are many available, here is a good list:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/9089/what-driver-should-i-use-for-my-usb-camera/

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-25**:
does camera1394 work with kinect?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-31**:
No, it does not.